# Fetch data from some desktop application to python

Tags: python

I am using a desktop application that takes some input data from some sensors using a dongle, processes the data shows some output on the screen. I want to transfer the data input as well as output to my python file to apply some ML algorithms on it.
Does anyone have any idea how this can be done, is there any kind of data scraping for this or do I have to write some python code to fetch the data?
Someone asked me to learn data streaming to do this.
Please tell me everything that is available for this.

**Note** : the application works offline on local machine, and I want the live data transfer from that application to python.

I have not tried anything yet, this thing is very new to me.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you face? Please see [ask]. As is, your question is way too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: If the application displays the data on the screen, google "python screen scraping".

Comment: If it saves its results in a file, try to search for a library that reads the files of that application. If you can't find it, you'll have to write it yourself, after researching the file format. This might require reverse engineering if the application doesn't document the format.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience and lack of info provided, I am using an application that receives EEG signals wirelessly from a wearable headgear. After some research I found that the application supports **LSL (Labstreaming Layer)**, that can be used to fetch the data from that app, as pyls library is available in python for the very specific purpose.